Can certain ensembles of equipment reveal the vectorial descriptions of the electric and magnetic fields at specific points in space?
The title of this post pretty much says it all. I would like to know if equipment exists that can, at some position $(x,y,z)$ in space, provide simultaneous vectorial descriptions of the electric field $\vec{E}$ and magnetic field $\vec{B}$ as functions of time $t$ (though, obviously, restricted by some sampling rate). I am vaguely familiar with magnetometers and electrometers...but uncertain if the data that they collect can be converted into vectorial descriptions of the form: $\vec{E}(x,y,z,t)=E_x(t)\hat{i}+E_y(t)\hat{j}+E_z(t)\hat{k}$ and $\vec{B}(x,y,z,t)=B_x(t)\hat{i}+B_y(t)\hat{j}+B_z(t)\hat{k}$. Given that this question is about 'real equipment', I recognize that the vectors are probably better expressed as being representative of a spatial average about the point $(x,y,z)$.

For visible light the fields oscillate 500 trillion times per second. Do you want to measure those oscillations? Or just their amplitude, frequency, and polarization?

I'm not sure I understand the question. Yes, I would like to measure time varying E and B fields. I recognize that there are technological limits to temporal sampling rates. If the purpose of your comment is to indicate that detection of light's temporal influence on the E and B fields is currently not achievable, then fair enough...but my question remains.

@Ghoster I see you updated your comment. I'm not sure why you believe this post is specifically about light. I just want to know if there is equipment that can report the vector descriptions of the electric field and magnetic field over time.

I don't think so. I think that the measurements we take are coordinates and that we then infer the vectorial nature of the electric and magnetic firlds. We don't have a direct measurement of their vectorial nature.

Thank you for the response; could you please clarify what you mean by 'coordinates'?
